# Can't access site on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a WordPress site. I created a page template that I'm using for index page for only visitors (it is set as a homepage in Wordpress admin settings -> reading). I used the following code in the page template to achieve this:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( home_url('/questions-listing/') ); 
exit;

}

get_header();
```

If a user is logged in, they don't see this index page, they are redirected to the page indicated above.

It works fine, but only on desktop. On mobilephones I'm getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

What I tried so far:

- Emtied cache and cookies in browsers
- Tried it on different browsers
- Checked the URLs in WordPress general settings to see if there is any differences

Just in case, here is the content of my .htaccess file also

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add the code via function in your functions.php.

```
function redirect_function() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    wp_redirect( home_url('/questions-listing/') ); 
    exit;

    }
}
add_action('init', 'redirect_function');
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why this is the case. But I had this occur once and it was remedied by explicitly specifying what to do on mobile. Something like the following may work for you:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if(wp_is_mobile()){
        wp_redirect( esc_url(home_url('/questions-listing/')) ); 
        exit;

     }
    else{
        wp_redirect( esc_url(home_url('/questions-listing/')) ); 
        exit;
     }
}

get_header();
```